# How does 雜's 2021 meanings appertain to its semantic component 衣?

Tags: etymology

[image]

[I screenshot Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E9%9B%9C#). If I had to guess, is the etymology related to the fact that clothing can be mixed or piled up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

杂/雜 originally refers to assortment of colors, referring to clothes that are multi-colored. You could think of it as multiple cloths of different colors sewn together to create a multi-colored garment. Its meaning is closely related to 集 as well. From there, the definition evolved to mean 'mixed' and 'miscellaneous'.

集 is doubling up both being the phonetic as well as semantic component for 雜.
集 refers to a gathering/assembly of birds (originally 3 birds 雦). A tree is where birds often gather.

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%9D%82

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%9B%86